# Show and hide component by clicking on a row in angular 7

Tags: angular7

I have a table if i am clicking on any of the row in a table, it will display  more detailed information about the row in right side of the table.

I have declared Boolean variable declared on the ts and i will set to true or false.

Now the problem is,  If i click on the 1st row, it will fetch the details and display it. If i click on either 1st row or any row in the table previously displayed details on the right wont be displayed.

Actually what i want to do is, i click on 1st row , it should display the details. If i click on anyother row, previously shown details should be hided, and new details should be displayed. How can i achieve this by using only angular 7 & typescript.

ts:

```
show = false; 
details(id:number){
this.show= !this.show;          
     //inject service to fetch the data 
 }


<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-5">
    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let order of Orders" (click)="details(order.id)"   
            class='clickable-row'>
               <td>  //display details </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table> 
 </div>

 <div class= "col-md-6">
   <div *ngIf="show"> 
      <mat-card> 
         <mat-card-content>
             //display details here 
         </mat-card-content> 
      </mat-card>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this.show= !this.show; does not seems correct, as it will show the content on first click, hide it on second, show it on 3rd and so on. But you haven't described such behavior, so I guess the issue is different than that and lies in the code you haven't posted in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build a child component in the current component just for displaying the details the pass the details of the particular row down to the child component using property binding that way you will have access to it when you use @input() in the child component. It will change each time since angular will do the tougher job for you at the background

Answer (score 0):

Use [Property Interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation).

```
<div class= "col-md-6">
 <div *ngIf="show"> 
  <mat-card> 
   <mat-card-content>
         {{RowDetails}}
     </mat-card-content> 
  </mat-card>
  </div>
  </div>
```

In your .ts file, have a property called RowDetails initialized as an empty string(or w/e). In the onClick event, set RowDetails to the details for that row.